# How to allow non-admin user update app which is installed for all users

Tags: wix, windows-installer, updates, administrator

We have developed a Windows .NET+WPF app and a .msi installer. The app is always installed for all users by admin. We would like the app to be automatically updated from predefined location (a shared folder in a network) on start. I think we can just have a code in the app which downloads a new .msi from the shared folder and then starts it. But the .msi needs to have administrative privileges to install for all users. Is there any way to give right to all users to update the app to a new version? Can we give them something during the initial installation, what everybody can run but it runs "as administrator" to install the new version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, that's the standard behavior when doing a minor upgrade.  See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/authoring-packages-without-the-uac-dialog-box

For major upgrade, UAC elevation will be required each time unless you can also write a helper service that advertises / blesses the MSI using the msiexec /jm command.